# Memory limit for 32bit application on 64bit windows 7?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, 32-bit

What it the accessible memory limit for 32bit application on 64bit windows 7? Is it 2GB the same as with 32bit Windows 7? or higher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is - it depends.  If the 32-bit application is 'large address aware', it will be able to allocate up to 4GB of virtual address space.

To find out if an application is large address aware, you can use the dumpbin tool to examine the headers, eg: "dumpbin.exe /HEADERS c:\path\to\my\executable.exe".

Look for a line which says "Application can handle large (>2GB) addresses".

If the application is not large address aware, it will be stuck at the usual 2GB limit for 32-bit applications.